# Spring: Exception when trying to start server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

When I run the Application.java file I get this exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

I'm using eclipse with gradle

Application.Java:

```
package com.overip.server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

The whole exception thrown:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.0.2.RELEASE)

2014-10-29 08:41:39.629  INFO 122080 --- [           main] com.overip.server.Application            : Starting Application on Dell-PC with PID 122080 (started by Fady & Emad in C:\Users\Fady & Emad\workspace\OverIP)
2014-10-29 08:41:39.688  INFO 122080 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6d463b81: startup date [Wed Oct 29 08:41:39 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-10-29 08:41:40.619  INFO 122080 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/workspace/OverIP/bin/, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.0.2.RELEASE/fb26276f8400658e15d571350c5b577dfe40567a/spring-boot-starter-web-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/mysql/mysql-connector-java/5.1.33/8af455a9a3267e6664cafc87ace71a4e4ef02837/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.0.2.RELEASE/699771411accffc41656db59ae51dd6663a653d6/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.0.2.RELEASE/58b239d692c4fab48dc8c430eabd527a2e153816/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.0.2.RELEASE/ccab7d782c8a8bf95c06573edd2f40d7da332e36/spring-boot-starter-test-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/17.0/9c6ef172e8de35fd8d4d8783e4821e57cdef7445/guava-17.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.6.0/39a9e4b49ded46aa1b67d492fe287c4cebcd815c/retrofit-1.6.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/b1b6ea3b7e4aa4f492509a4952029cd8e48019ad/commons-io-2.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/5959582d97d8b61f4d154ca9e495aafd16726e34/servlet-api-2.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jetty/1.0.2.RELEASE/6f8da7ee1e540b2f21f99946ca74eb1726f2fd82/spring-boot-starter-jetty-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.11/4e031bb61df09069aeb2bffb4019e7a5034a4ee0/junit-4.11.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/f6f66e966c70a83ffbdb6f17a0919eaf7c8aca7f/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.0.3.RELEASE/138d28200d97f4affe9ccaa47fab54718b438319/spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.0.3.RELEASE/41eabd53fd4ba5ba2b2d8af6c256a3741f65c2f3/spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.0.3.RELEASE/dcedf5329d7092d66cc9d2496687a5f29d883eb6/spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.0.3.RELEASE/40b25b3a693cb4cc382ddf2e69ff1b29c75a2e7d/spring-expression-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.0.3.RELEASE/782a71a312dc307fa531023aa66247b9b4a109d/spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.0.2.RELEASE/8d1a06e468b16577075db27123091758b6f880af/spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.0.2.RELEASE/3a70e3021aec334ee8b1a454ea791d27997a7191/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/2b8019b6249bb05d81d3a3094e468753e2b21311/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/56003dcd0a31deea6391b9e2ef2f2dc90b205a92/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.7/def21bc1a6e648ee40b41a84f1db443132913105/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.7/d521cb26a9c4407caafcec302e7804b048b07cea/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.1.2/2d23694879c2c12f125dac5076bdfd5d771cc4cb/logback-core-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/b316e9737eea25e9ddd6d88eaeee76878045c6b2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.0.2.RELEASE/47a20c5bad47916ca99d768782de12c54b707a00/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.0.2.RELEASE/a6cbc3adc8d95a0e5405d3c1ca30ad8e6bed1cf1/spring-boot-starter-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/73cbb494a912866c4c831a178c3a2a9169f4eaad/snakeyaml-1.13.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.3.0/f5e853a20b60758922453d56f9ae1e64af5cb3da/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.3.3/7d8c5d79cc99995e21e6f955857312d8409f02a1/jackson-core-2.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.3.3/63b77400b5f1cf83a81823562c48d3120ef5518e/jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.0.3.RELEASE/4d5066f31ea4b9c58957bf8c0c213b13ed44c1c5/spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.3.RELEASE/d6fd9778619ab87a41ae3aa879a53ee60f160c08/spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.0.2.RELEASE/ec33fd737d646dc4e092176bee856245e2f02f8c/spring-boot-actuator-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.7.4/e49a5c0acee8fd66225dc1d031692d132323417f/aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.7.4/d9d511e417710492f78bb0fb291a629d56bf4216/aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.objenesis/objenesis/1.0/9b473564e792c2bdf1449da1f0b1b5bff9805704/objenesis-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/c3264abeea62c4d2f367e21484fbb40c7e256393/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-test/4.0.3.RELEASE/76b870a5aa132b4c0dd78cd061feb3e1652cddd1/spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.4/a60a5e993c98c864010053cb901b7eab25306568/gson-2.2.4.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util/8.1.14.v20131031/43063284480a41eca024dc8852452eedf6379c16/jetty-util-8.1.14.v20131031.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-xml/8.1.14.v20131031/8732c74817fef6d2e3e667636e6c4f27fb4cada9/jetty-xml-8.1.14.v20131031.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-continuation/8.1.14.v20131031/e3396abd21360191c2277e848eff489b58bba45d/jetty-continuation-8.1.14.v20131031.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-io/8.1.14.v20131031/12f6f92d7e58349501f2cfc0716b8f1c6a2962eb/jetty-io-8.1.14.v20131031.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http/8.1.14.v20131031/8dd4e01b374e16cf0335b7975a7aa0a57396d5da/jetty-http-8.1.14.v20131031.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server/8.1.14.v20131031/7f7f9b929b9d9169dd68f36327c819ab9a03a661/jetty-server-8.1.14.v20131031.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-security/8.1.14.v20131031/d6fd7add8e6015a95558b67b43edf7752a925884/jetty-security-8.1.14.v20131031.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlet/8.1.14.v20131031/2ea127b7001965201d28ce715f5754573205c4ae/jetty-servlet-8.1.14.v20131031.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-webapp/8.1.14.v20131031/1f29371c74381ac42f961e9b984a7af28cc62093/jetty-webapp-8.1.14.v20131031.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/aaaa85845fb5c59da00193f06b8e5278d8bf3f8/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.servlet.jsp/2.2.0.v201112011158/80b4ffe7c26ee97313bea2ddda5835fd38812ee4/javax.servlet.jsp-2.2.0.v201112011158.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/org.apache.jasper.glassfish/2.2.2.v201112011158/3945afe6a042228a92da320aec3fa1bc1308183b/org.apache.jasper.glassfish-2.2.2.v201112011158.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl/1.2.0.v201105211821/db594f1c8fc00d536f6d135bd7f8a9a99a6b8eea/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.0.v201105211821.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish/1.2.0.v201112081803/2c4baa72af1d3aae3a1e029d4f8ca07498dabbe0/org.apache.taglibs.standard.glassfish-1.2.0.v201112081803.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.el/2.2.0.v201108011116/ec8944c11833d84b0283a5afbad0fafb264f86a9/javax.el-2.2.0.v201108011116.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/com.sun.el/2.2.0.v201108011116/15f7774c3fa514835a371f47c152317704ea411a/com.sun.el-2.2.0.v201108011116.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/org.eclipse.jdt.core/3.7.1/5b79bfee0852ca685e33cab74496fa3400271b5b/org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.7.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/Fady%20&%20Emad/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-jsp/8.1.14.v20131031/87dc1723a32113d74be2420d940f6825e3b6af42/jetty-jsp-8.1.14.v20131031.jar]
2014-10-29 08:41:40.622  INFO 122080 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6d463b81: startup date [Wed Oct 29 08:41:39 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-10-29 08:41:40.629  WARN 122080 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6d463b81: startup date [Wed Oct 29 08:41:39 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:152)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:329)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
at com.overip.server.Application.main(Application.java:16)

2014-10-29 08:41:40.630  WARN 122080 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6d463b81: startup date [Wed Oct 29 08:41:39 EET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:888)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:152)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:329)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
at com.overip.server.Application.main(Application.java:16)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: class "javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:236)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:144)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:113)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:75)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:44)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader$TrackedConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:400)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:324)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
at com.overip.server.Application.main(Application.java:16)
```

Comment: For starters you don't need the `@EnableWebMvc` that is already done and detected by Spring Boot. The error suggests that you have a jar in your lib folder containing the `javax.servlet` classes, don't. The scope of those should be provided. I strongly suggest just using the Spring Boot starter projects as those manage the dependencies pretty well.

Comment: Yeah that was it thanks, I removed the javax.servlet classes and it worked! thanks